# SMS text solution

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sms

With google app engine, is there a way to send a text message from a cell phone, to the app(written in python) and have the data stored in the app database. then be able to retreive it from the app in a browser. and vice versa. after searching a few Days I have not come close to finding this answer, or a cloud based solution. Think of drop box for say Poems. you can write a poem or haiku in sms and text it to your account. you can use a mobile phone app to publish it to your account. or use the web based service to post it to your account. the end result is being able to access the data on all fronts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use Twilio to send text messages from [AppEngine](http://www.twilio.com/gallery/technologies/google-app-engine) using [Twilio SMS API](http://www.twilio.com/api/sms).
2. Check out the code of weather by phone app documented [here](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/10/build-voice-app-in-cloud-and-enter.html) on Google Appengine blog:
3. Weather by phone app (python+appengine) [how-to](http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/weatherbyphone)
4. I have heard that [Tropo is also good](https://github.com/tropo/tropo-webapi-python). Try it out, it's [Free for developers](https://www.tropo.com/pricing/).

I have never done it personally, but that should do the trick.

Comment: If you have any questions, feel free to let me know (I work at Twilio)

Comment: I just looked at the twilio website. It is a very viable solution to the app I want to build. The only set back I can see is the short sms number being quite expensive.

Comment: Try out tropo, is free for developers (https://www.tropo.com/pricing/). @John Comments?

Comment: We give every new customer $30 in free credit to start with. That's 3000 text messages and more than plenty for most people to get their apps built and tested. Feel free to try both services to see which you prefer and if you have issues try our world-class support at help@twilio.com